# Is $P(E | \bar F) + P(\bar E | \bar F) = 1$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is $P(E \, | \, \bar{F}) + P(\bar{E} \, | \, \bar F) = 1$?

I tried using Venn diagram and here's what I get:

[image: Venn diagram of E and F.]

The red region shows $P(E \, | \, \bar{F})$ and the blue region shows $P(\bar{E} \, | \, \bar{F})$.

Clearly it is not $1$ but my book says it is. Where have I misunderstood?

Comment: You probably confuse the relative complement and the conditional probability.

Comment: You are confusing $/$ , that is conditional probability, with $\cap$, the intersection. Conditional probability $P(E / F)$ requires that you take the ratio $\frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)}$, so it is not the probability of some event in the space, but rather a ratio of two probabilities, which can't be represented on the Venn diagram.

Comment: Is $P(E/F)$ a conditional probability. If so, then recall the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Is it not possible to sketch conditional probability on venn diagram @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @Abcd You can sketch it. Just cut out the circle for $F$. Now, this is your new sample space.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $(E \cap \bar F) \cup (\bar E \cap \bar F) = \bar F$ and
- $(E \cap \bar F) \cap (\bar E \cap \bar F) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

Since $E$ and $\bar{E}$ are disjoint events we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(E|\bar{F}) + \mathbb{P}(\bar{E}|\bar{F}) = \mathbb{P}(E \cup \bar{E}|\bar{F}) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega|\bar{F}) = 1.$$

The first step follows from the additivity axiom of probability and the last follows from the norming axiom.  Your diagram does not accurately show the conditional probabilities: the first is the *relative* size of the red area in the union of both the red and blue areas, and the second is the *relative* size of the blue area in the union of both the red and blue areas, which sum to the whole area (i.e., one).

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive view, to make the parallel with your Venn diagram is to realize that in your case $1$ (=your "universe") is not the "full picture" by only $\bar{F}$.
This is apparent from the formula:
$$
P(E|\bar{F})=\frac{P(E,\bar{F})}{P(\bar{F})}
$$
To reword what I said, your normalization factor is now $\bar{F}$.

Obviously you have:
\begin{align*}
P(E|\bar{F})+P(\bar{E}|\bar{F}) &=\frac{P(E,\bar{F})}{P(\bar{F})}+\frac{P(\bar{E},\bar{F})}{P(\bar{F})} \\ &=\frac{P(E,\bar{F})+P(\bar{E},\bar{F})}{P(\bar{F})} \\ &=\frac{P(\bar{F})}{P(\bar{F})} \\ &= 1
\end{align*}